# How can ensure that the variables i entered in my entry widget is used in the loop function?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Investment Calculator')
```

#use the entry widget to input data
#use the widt?h to increase the width, use fg and bg to change colour, use boarder to change
#boader line

```
x1= Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x2=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x3=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x1.grid(row=0, column=0)
x2.grid(row=1, column=0)
x3.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

#to ensure that I am able  to read my input as integer

```
def click():
  P=int(x1.get())
  ROI=float(x2.get())
  months=int(x3.get())
  print(P, ROI, months) # for test

P=IntVar()
ROI=IntVar()
months=IntVar()
bt = Button(root, text="click", command= click)
bt.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

#to enter a default text into the entry widget, use the insert button)

```
count = 0
capital=0
def mycalculator():
   for i in range(0,months,1):
    capital1 = P + P*ROI
    P1 = capital1
    interest = capital1-P
    P=P1
    count = count + i
    while count==months:
        break
b = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=mycalculator)
b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

#to ensure it continues running in a loop, I have to create a loop

```
root.mainloop()
```

I kept on getting this error
TypeError: 'IntVar' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: can you post the full error code too

Comment: see your months is just an instance, you have to say `months.get()` and also convert it to `int` by `int(months.get())`

Comment: From your code, `P`, `ROI` and `months` are `IntVar`.  So `.get()` should be used on them to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the range function expects an int but your giving it a tk.IntVar().

All you have to do is convert the intvar into a int using the .get() methord

```
...
def mycalculator():
   for i in range(0,months.get(),1):
    capital1 = P + P*ROI
    P1 = capital1
...
```

Comment: actually i think by default `get()` method also returns a string, even tho it says `IntVar()`, so you might want to say `int(month.get())`

Comment: @CoolCloud `IntVar.get()` will return integer type.

Comment: @acw1668 oh okay, i thought i read somewer like that, my bad